# strange cell height in table when printing in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have the following html file.

= File no longer available =

The problem starts when the page is printed in chrome. Chrome randomly increases the height of some cells in the preview and the printed file.

When you use Internet Explorer everything is printed as it should.

Try it for yourself, open the file in chrome and press ctrl + p you can see on page 4 en page 6 that one row is higher then the others.

Comment: First thought is could it be somethign to do with dutch language?

Comment: Just tried amd it looks fine in preview for me (Im not printing this at work tho ;))

Comment: Try setting a fixed table-cell height for your cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to productforums.google.com it is a known issue and Google is working on it. Just have to wait and see

Comment: Do you have a direct link to that known issue?

Answer (score -1):

use `</td>` and `</tr>` tags too. you use whitespaces after words and when chrome calculates cell inner text length, these whitespaces are displayed. take them off. Also upgrade page structure to html standarts.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Set line height property and dont use table title.. I mean, all td tags are must be same height.

[image]